# Modificar HttpContext.Current.User está quebrando o bundle optimization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Fiz vários testes e pude constatar que ao modificar o `HttpContext.Current.User` `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` (Global.asax.cs) obtenho um Internal Server Error na requisição do bundle concatenado/minificado.

Segue código citado:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest( Object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        HttpContext.Current.User = SessionManager.GetCurrentUser( Request );

        if (IsWebApiRequest())
        {
            HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior( SessionStateBehavior.Required );
        }
    }

    private bool IsWebApiRequest()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.StartsWith( WebApiConfig.UrlPrefixRelative );
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aí só tem o cabeçalho da requisição com erro. Qual o erro de verdade?

Comment: A requisição não me gera um Http Response no console. Gera um html com um erro de runtime.

https://gist.github.com/cbfranca/5b32461f6613486e3d11

Comment: Um chute: acho para para Bundling não há usuário associado ao contexto. Já tentou debugar esse evento?

Comment: Era exatamente isso @CiganoMorrisonMendez. Obg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema era que o `SessionManager.GetCurrentUser( Request );` esta null e ao atribuir ao `HttpContext.Current.User` o bundle gerava uma exceção.